# Convert glm::vec4 to glm::vec3

Tags: glm-math

How do I convert a `glm::vec4` to a `glm::vec3`?

Only `x`, `y`, `z` is required- the `w` component can be dropped.

In GLSL this can be done with `.xyz`[1], but in glm this results in a compile error:

```
error: 'glm::vec4' has no member named 'xyz'
```

[1] http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations#Components

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just use vec3 **constructor**. Here, on 0.9.5 branch:

```
glm::vec4 v4(1, 2, 3, 4);
glm::vec3 v(v4);
printf("%s\n", glm::to_string(v).c_str());
```

and gives this output

> fvec3(1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000)

Answer (score 29):

Swizzling is not enabled by default in glm as it uses macros which might cause naming conflicts. To enable it:

```
#define GLM_SWIZZLE
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

In glm, swizzling is done using functions:

```
vec3 v3 = v4.xyz();
```

See: http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00002.html